# Hosting angular and nodejs on the same domain (cpanel)

Tags: node.js, angular

I have my angular application running on subdomain.maindomain.com
My api is running on api.maindomain.com

My nodejs and angular are both hosted on the same subdomain.

I have a proxy.conf.json file that looks like this:

```
   {
    "/api": {
        "target": "api.maindomain.com/api/",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

My start script is:

```
 "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json -o",
```

Whenever I build and deploy my app, I can access: api.maindomain.com/api/users through the browser or Postman and it works 100%. It gives me the desired API response.

When I try to make the API call on angular on subdomain.maindomain.com however, the api call goes to
subdomain.maindomain.com/api/users
when it should be calling
api.subdomain.com/api/users

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy setting is only for the development purposes. It was implmented to make it easier for the developers to deal with the Backends that are hosted in anohter domain (different host or completly another domain). For this, it won't be shipped with the production deployment.

The `api.maindomain.com` is actually other host and different than the `subdomain.maindomain.com`, so the request will fail.

The `origin` header is responsable for this. It is added by the browser for every request automatically and equals the same domain you are accessing.

When trying to access the API by the Browser it will always work. When accessing the API directly, the Browser will add the `origin` header with the same domain (As you are accessing it from the same domain), so there will no issues with it. For Postman, there is no origin header when sending so it won't fail too.

To fix this, you either need to host both of them on the same host, or you will have to enable CORS for your subdomain. If you are using Express, you can use the [CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) similar to this:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})
```

You can find more info about the CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I will try this later when I get home from work and if it works okay, I will mark this answer as correct. On the other hand what would happen if my server+angular would be hosted on the same subdomain, for instance my angular app is:

subdomain.maindomain.com
and my api is 
subdomain.maindomain.com/api

This works for me and I get the api results, but I am using the .htaccess file that I found here: https://gist.github.com/julianpoemp/bcf277cb56d2420cc53ec630a04a3566

If I use this .htaccess file my API returns nothing, but if I don't use it then my api works fine?

Comment: I believe the redirect rule will redirect all requests coming from the client to the subdomain to the index.html, so it fails. You can check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937279/angular-and-php-htaccess-file-redirecting-problem

Comment: The .htaccess for the api.

Comment: Actually I'm not really expert in .htaccess. I suggest to ask a question in a separate topic